# how to generate multiple html files with angular-cli builds?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, html-webpack-plugin

I have an angular project with manual setup (no angular-cli) and configured the build to generate multiple html files using HTML Webpack Plugin. Now, I am planning to move to angular-cli and wondering how can i generate multiple html files along with index.html?

Comment: what `html` files? do you have like multiple `index.html's`

Comment: kind of. our app deployment and monitoring tools needs a ping url to verify the status of app in the web server, so to decide whether to include in the loadbalancer or not. I was using html-webpack-plugin to create a new folder and a index file to support these needs.

Answer (score 3):

I do not quite understand the purpose of you having multiple html files.

You might need to check this angular cli issue: [Support for multiple html pages](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3604). But in case if you want to setup `angular cli` to be able produce multiple apps, then check this issues:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3629
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7124
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7309

However you can always customize the default `angular cli` `webpack config` anyway you want by using [eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) feature. Check [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6302) on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom-webpack with plugins:

- angular.json

```json
"options": {
   "customWebpackConfig": {
      "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js"
   }
}
```

- custom-webpack.config.js

```js
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
export default env => {
 ...
 return {
  ...
  "plugins": [
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     template: 'index.html',
     minify: true
   })
  ]
 }
}
```